# How to inject Spring-managed CacheRegionFactory in Spring Hibernate 5 LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hazelcast, spring-orm

### Problem

The LocalSessionFactoryBean that comes with Spring ORM Hibernate 4 allowed for injecting a CacheRegionFactory through standard dependency injection for the *cacheRegionFactory* property.

[Hibernate 4 LocalSessionFactoryBean Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setCacheRegionFactory-org.hibernate.cache.spi.RegionFactory->)

Now for the LocalSessionFactoryBean that ships with Spring ORM Hibernate 5 there is no such property anymore.

[Hibernate 5 LocalSessionFactoryBean Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html)

Being able to inject the region factory is very handy when finer control is needed over the cache configuration, especially when configuring Hibernate as second-level cache with Spring.

My use case is dynamically specifying members of a TCP/IP Hazelcast cluster based on my app configuration file. Hazelcast is used as second level cache.

### Question

How can I inject a Spring-managed cache region factory into a Hibernate 5 LocalSessionFactoryBean through Spring dependency injection? Suggestions for different approaches also welcome.

### Details

Hibernate version: 5.1.0, Spring/Spring ORM version: 4.2.5, Hazelcast version: 3.6.4

Comment: Any solution find regarding this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own session factory bean extending from `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and overriding the method `buildSessionFactory` to provide Hibernate with your own region factory via `ServiceRegistryBuilder`:

```
class MySessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean { 
  private final RegionFactory regionFactory;

  MySessionFactoryBean(RegionFactory regionFactory) {
    this.regionFactory = regionFactory;
  }  

  @Override
  protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = sfb.getStandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
    serviceRegistryBuilder.addService(RegionFactory.class, regionFactory);

    return sfb.buildSessionFactory();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has been recently restored, and the fix will be available Spring Framework 5.1 RC1.

Issue link to Spring Framework JIRA: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-17043

The answer from Arthur will work, but there is also a slightly shorter variant:

```
public class MyLocalSessionFactoryBean extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

    private RegionFactory regionFactory;

    @Required
    public void setRegionFactory(RegionFactory regionFactory) {
        this.regionFactory = regionFactory;
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
        sfb.getProperties().put(AvailableSettings.CACHE_REGION_FACTORY, regionFactory);
        return sfb.buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the `hibernate.cache.region.factory_class` property. Example usage:

`<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
    value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>`

More info here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#caching-config-provider

Comment: Sure thanks, I am aware of that. I need to inject a Spring-managed custom region factory class / bean where I can utilize my other Spring-managed components. I have updated my question to clarify that.